# Sorted list not sorted when binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, list

I have a sorted list. When I bind it to a listbox, it does not shows the item in an ordered manner.

```
territoryListBox.BeginUpdate();
this.Text = ((INamedEntity)_currentList[0]).Name;
territoryListBox.DataSource = _currentList;
territoryListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
territoryListBox.Sorted = true;
territoryListBox.EndUpdate();
```

The first item in the list is, say, A. The this.Text shows "A", which is the first item in the list. But the listbox shows:

```
B
C
A
```

_currentList is a IList<>

Comment: When you say you have a Sorted List do you mean the list is sorted before you bind it or that the list can be sorted?

Comment: I mean the items are already in the correct order in the list before I bind it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you swallowing an exception? When I try this I get (when setting `Sorted`) an `ArgumentException`:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

IMO, sort the list first - and bind to that; however, a quick test shows that setting `Sorted` **before** setting the `DataSource` works too - i.e.

```
territoryListBox.Sorted = true;
territoryListBox.DataSource = yourListOfData;
territoryListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: I'm not swallowing an exception. I don't know why you get this exception.

I tried your trick to sort the list first and it's now working.

territoryListBox.BeginUpdate();
territoryListBox.Sorted = true;
territoryListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
territoryListBox.DataSource = _currentList;
territoryListBox.EndUpdate();

_currentList is an IList<>

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, try [ListBox.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx).  Obviously, that should not be necessary, but something's going haywire.

Comment: There's no ListBox.Sort method.